# Python NonExistentTimeError - Different behavior in different machines

Tags: python, datetime, windows-server-2016, pytz, timestamp-with-timezone

I am facing a strange behavior when applying using the `tz_localize` function from datetime.

The peace of code is the following

```
infer_dst = np.array([False]*df.shape[0])
try:
    df.index=df.index.tz_localize(self.tzs,ambiguous=infer_dst)
except pytz.NonExistentTimeError as e:
    self.logger.warning(f"DST between {t_ini} and {t_end} in host {ctrl_inf['host']}")
    self.logger.warning(str(e))
```

Here where I leave we should be entering the daylight saving period but this year we are not going to have it.

The weird thing is that when I run this code in a server (Windows Server 2016) I receive a lot of `NonExistentTimeError` messages. But if I run the same code on my laptop for the same period of time it works fine.

I thought that maybe the cause could be that the auto daylight saving time is adjusted to automatic in the server but it is also set to ON in my laptop (this is something set by the IT company and I was not able to turn it off)
Just to contextualize the situation a little bit more. The dataframe df holds historical data from a PIMS system.

Does anyone have ever seen something like that?
Thanks

UPDATE

Definetelly the problem is something in the Window Server. The problem happens with data in the interval from 0h to 1h (24h format) of Nov 7th 2021. As I was not able to fix the server I come up with a not very beautiful solution.

```
infer_dst = np.array([False]*df1.shape[0])
try:                        
    df1.index=df1.index.tz_localize(self.tzs,ambiguous=infer_dst)
except pytz.NonExistentTimeError as e:
    self.logger.warning(f'DST between {t_ini} and {t_end} in host {host}')
    self.logger.warning(str(e))
    #try to remove the period with problem
    remove_index=[]
    for k in range(len(df1)-1):
    try:
        df1.index[k].tz_localize(self.tzs)
    except:
        remove_index.append(k)
    
    df1.drop(df1.index[remove_index],inplace=True)

    infer_dst = np.array([False]*df1.shape[0])       
                        
    df1.index=df1.index.tz_localize(self.tzs,ambiguous=infer_dst)
```

Comment: are you using the same pandas and pytz version on the server and your notebook? what OS are you running on your notebook?

Comment: Yes.. all the same. I am checking here with a IT colleague and it seems that the problem is in someway related to a KB that MS realeased to fix the DST here in Brazil. For some reason this KB is not working on the WIndows Server 2016. The error is happening for the period starting on 07-nov-2021 at 0h.

Comment: re-reading the question after your edit, it seems to me that this is a Windows-issue, not a Python/pandas/pytz problem as I thought at first.

Comment: Yes. This is what I think

Comment: should be another +1 on the "store date/time in UTC" list in any case. you can always convert that to some user time zone based on [IANA's time zone rules](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).